# Ansible: How to print all the inventory hostnames with serial number in order?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am a novice to Ansible. I am trying to print all the inventory hosts with serial number (sl.no) using a Jinja template which would be transformed to a `.csv` file. I have this playbook to ping all the hosts and get the status.

```yaml
- hosts: '{{ host }}'
  gather_facts: true
  become: true      

  tasks:
    - name: Pinging Host {{ host }}
      action: ping
      register: var_ping
```

I want to print all hostnames and its ping status with serial order number.

How to achieve this?

Expected output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXQD1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) *ansible_play_hosts* and *ansible_play_hosts_all*. Quoting:

> **ansible_play_hosts**: List of hosts in the current play run, not limited by the serial. Failed/Unreachable hosts are excluded from this list.

> **ansible_play_hosts_all**: List of all the hosts that were targeted by the play

1. **Create the serial numbers**

For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_12
test_13
test_14
```

and the abridged result of the *ping* module. The hosts test_12 and test_14 failed.

```yaml
TASK [ping] ****************************************************************
fatal: [test_12]: FAILED! => changed=false 
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_13]
fatal: [test_14]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
```

gives

```yaml
ansible_play_hosts_all: ['test_11', 'test_12', 'test_13', 'test_14']
ansible_play_hosts: ['test_11', 'test_13']
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
failed_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|difference(ansible_play_hosts) }}"
failed_hosts_dict: "{{ dict(failed_hosts|product(['fail'])) }}"
passed_hosts_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|product(['success'])) }}"
hosts_dict: "{{ passed_hosts_dict|combine(failed_hosts_dict) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
failed_hosts: ['test_12', 'test_14']
failed_hosts_dict: {'test_12': 'fail', 'test_14': 'fail'}
passed_hosts_dict: {'test_11': 'success', 'test_13': 'success'}
hosts_dict: {'test_11': 'success', 'test_13': 'success', 'test_12': 'fail', 'test_14': 'fail'}
```

Create and test a template. Fit the [sorting](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.sort) to you needs

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
          {% for k,v in hosts_dict.items()|sort() %}
          {{ loop.index }},{{ k }},{{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
    1,test_11,success
    2,test_12,fail
    3,test_13,success
    4,test_14,fail
```

If this is what you want write the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/status.csv
        content: |
          Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
          {% for k,v in hosts_dict.items()|sort() %}
          {{ loop.index }},{{ k }},{{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/status.csv 
Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
1,test_11,success
2,test_12,fail
3,test_13,success
4,test_14,fail
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    failed_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|difference(ansible_play_hosts) }}"
    failed_hosts_dict: "{{ dict(failed_hosts|product(['fail'])) }}"
    passed_hosts_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|product(['success'])) }}"
    hosts_dict: "{{ passed_hosts_dict|combine(failed_hosts_dict) }}"

  tasks:

    - ping:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_play_hosts_all: {{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}
          ansible_play_hosts: {{ ansible_play_hosts }}
          failed_hosts: {{ failed_hosts }}
          failed_hosts_dict: {{ failed_hosts_dict }}
          passed_hosts_dict: {{ passed_hosts_dict }}
          hosts_dict: {{ hosts_dict }}
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
          {% for k,v in hosts_dict.items()|sort() %}
          {{ loop.index }},{{ k }},{{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/status.csv
        content: |
          Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
          {% for k,v in hosts_dict.items()|sort() %}
          {{ loop.index }},{{ k }},{{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

---

1. **Serial numbers are assigned in the inventory**

For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_11 sn=1
test_12 sn=2
test_13 sn=3
test_14 sn=4
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
failed_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|difference(ansible_play_hosts) }}"
failed_hosts_dict: |
  {% for host in failed_hosts %}
  {{ host }}:
    status: fail
    sn: {{ hostvars[host]['sn'] }}
  {% endfor %}
passed_hosts_dict: |
  {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
  {{ host }}:
    status: success
    sn: {{ hostvars[host]['sn'] }}
  {% endfor %}
hosts_list: "{{ passed_hosts_dict|from_yaml|
                combine(failed_hosts_dict|from_yaml)|
                dict2items|
                sort(attribute='value.sn')}}"
```

gives

```yaml
hosts_list:
  - key: test_11
    value:
      sn: 1
      status: success
  - key: test_12
    value:
      sn: 2
      status: fail
  - key: test_13
    value:
      sn: 3
      status: success
  - key: test_14
    value:
      sn: 4
      status: fail
```

Write the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/status.csv
        content: |
          Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
          {% for i in hosts_list %}
          {{ i.value.sn }},{{ i.key }},{{ i.value.status }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives the same result

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/status.csv 
Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
1,test_11,success
2,test_12,fail
3,test_13,success
4,test_14,fail
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    failed_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|difference(ansible_play_hosts) }}"
    failed_hosts_dict: |
      {% for host in failed_hosts %}
      {{ host }}:
        status: fail
        sn: {{ hostvars[host]['sn'] }}
      {% endfor %}
    passed_hosts_dict: |
      {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
      {{ host }}:
        status: success
        sn: {{ hostvars[host]['sn'] }}
      {% endfor %}
    hosts_list: "{{ passed_hosts_dict|from_yaml|
                    combine(failed_hosts_dict|from_yaml)|
                    dict2items|
                    sort(attribute='value.sn')}}"

  tasks:

    - ping:

    - debug:
        var: hosts_list
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_play_hosts_all: {{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}
          ansible_play_hosts: {{ ansible_play_hosts }}
          failed_hosts: {{ failed_hosts }}
          failed_hosts_dict: {{ failed_hosts_dict|from_yaml }}
          passed_hosts_dict: {{ passed_hosts_dict|from_yaml }}
          hosts_list: {{ hosts_list }}
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
          {% for i in hosts_list %}
          {{ i.value.sn }},{{ i.key }},{{ i.value.status }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/status.csv
        content: |
          Serial Number, Hostname, Ping Status
          {% for i in hosts_list %}
          {{ i.value.sn }},{{ i.key }},{{ i.value.status }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```